# New implementation/method of existing request mapping in controller

Tags: spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to look for a way to extend a controller such that I can use the existing request mapping but with a different implementation/method tied to it.

Say for example, below is a code snippet from **AdminBasicEntityController** in BLC where **viewAddEntityForm** method is tied to **/add** request mapping. Now I want to have my own logic of showing entityForm(Say Product entity) using **/add** request mapping. Is it possible?

```
@Controller("blAdminBasicEntityController")
@RequestMapping("/{sectionKey:.+}")
public class AdminBasicEntityController extends AdminAbstractController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewEntityList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,
            @PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVars,
            @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams) throws Exception {
            // default implementation
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewAddEntityForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,
            @PathVariable  Map<String, String> pathVars,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String entityType) throws Exception {
            // default implementation
    }
}
```

Also I found below mentioned information in the documentation of **AdminBasicEntityController**, so does it mean I can have controller for specific entity. If yes, how?

> The default implementation of the {@link #BroadleafAdminAbstractEntityController}. This delegates every call to super and does not provide any custom-tailored functionality. It is
>   responsible for rendering the admin for every entity that is not
>   explicitly customized by its own controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RequestMapping("/{sectionKey:.+}")` uses the generic path variable `sectionKey`, making the controller handle any requests that are not explicitly mapped.  For example,

```
/product
/product/add
/category
/category/add
/store
/store/add
```

may all be hitting this controller if these URLs have not been explicitly mapped to their own controllers.

To handle a specific URL yourself, you could do:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductAdminController {
  @RequestMapping("/add")
  public String viewAddEntityForm(...) { ... }
}
```

Now, the URL `/product/add` will be routed to this custom controller while all others will continue to get routed to the generic controller.